# JQuery: $(this).parent().$("#SOME_ELEMENT'S_ID_THATS_INSIDE_THE_PARENT")?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to use a div as the submit button for an html form because I don't like how the default button looks. The problem is that I have several identical forms and div-buttons on my page (they are added with jquery) so neither have a unique id. When I have more than one form on my page, the corresponding div-button submits the first form.

Each div-button and form are located within a larger container div. Is it possible to do something like:

```
$(".div_btn").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().$(".my_form").$("#my_submit").trigger("click")
});
```

where .div_btn is the div I'm using as a button, .my_form is the forms class, and #my_submit is the id of this form's submit button.

Comment: I have a feeling you are using IDs incorrectly. If you have an ID, why not just `$('#my_submit').trigger("click")`? (Edit: I re-read the question...IDs must be unique.)

Answer (score 2):

All IDs are supposed to be unique.  Create unique IDs for the forms.  Then use:

```
$("#uniqueFormId").submit();
```

As to the creation of unique IDs, a quick example:

The HTML:

```
<button id="formAdder">Add Form</button>
<div id="formHolder">
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formAdder").click(function() {  
    var formNum = $("form").length;   
    $("#formHolder").append("<form id='uniqueForm" + formNum + "'>Form Id is uniqueForm" +formNum+"</form>");
  });
});
```

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/3QQwZ/).

Comment: Hey Matthew, I wish I could do this but I'm adding the forms onto the page with JQuery. So you click a button and the form is created, allowing the user to create as many as they want. It would help if you could let me know a way to do this while assigning each form a unique id.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question will not achieve what you want to do since triggering a click on submit (by javascript) will not submit the form. This however will if you DOM is what i think it is :

```
$(".div_btn").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.div_btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('#my_submit').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: While this may work, you should never use the same ID more than once.  This could cause bugs later in development.  I've updated my answer to indicate how to create unique form IDs on the fly.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewJohnson, this may work now but it is not designed to be a best practice. You may want to post some of your JS and HTML and ask for help in refactoring.